# Errno 2 No such file or directory: '/root/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/' in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, chatbot, chatterbot

I am trying to create a simple chatbot in Google Colab. The code ran successfully for the first time, but when I tried to run it again the next day it shows the following error :-

---

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 4
> 5 trainer= ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
> ----> 6 trainer.train ("chatterbot.corpus.english")

> 2 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/chatterbot/corpus.py in read_corpus(file_name)
> 56         raise OptionalDependencyImportError(message)
> 57
> ---> 58     with io.open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
> 59         return yaml.load(data_file)
> 60

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/chatterbot_corpus/data/english'

I had not made any changes in the code. What is the problem?

```
    pip install chatterbot
```

```
    pip install chatterbot_corpus
```

```
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
    from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
    chatbot = ChatBot('mybot')


    trainer= ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)
    trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")
```

Comment: Pretty sure you didn't run the script from the same folder as last time, and it cannot find the english training data. Try to check your shell history with `history` in order to see where you did run the script from

Comment: I did factory reset runtime , and it is working fine now. I checked and I had ran the script from the same folder. Don't know what exactly caused the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This error arises when you get connected to a new runtime as it does not contain any of the pre-installed packages or files. I would suggest keeping the pip install commands in different code block and running it first then running the code also if you had any files in directory you gotta reupload it.

So I just ran your code in my colab and the problem is this:

```
!pip install chatterbot
!pip install chatterbot_corpus
```

just add the '!' before and it will work'.

Comment: Yes I have done that, I have kept the pip install code in different code block and ran them first, but it still shows the same problem

Comment: I updated my answer and checked , it runs fine now

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is working now without adding '!' . The code is the same but now it runs well.  I did factory reset runtime, maybe that helped.